# ASP.NET MVC View throwing CS1061 error related to type of model object passed as ViewDdata to a view

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working through the ASP.NET MVC article at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx.  (Note: Some of the constructs in this post were deprecated in MVC 1 RTM, so I've changed the code accordingly.  Perhaps that's my problem.)

In my LINQ to SQL .dbml (in *MyDB*.designer.cs) the Category class (compiler generated) is defined as follows:

```
namespace MVC_Basics_1.Models
{
    ...
    [Table(Name="dbo.Categories")]
    public partial class Category : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ...
    }
```

In my controller class I define a Categories action method as follows:

```
public ActionResult Categories()  // /Products/Categories/ maps here
{
    List<Category> categories = northwind.GetCategories();
    return View("Categories", categories);
}
```

I then create a Categories.aspx which is strongly typed as "MVC_Basics_1.Models.Category" which places the

```
<%@ ... Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MVC_Basics_1.Models.Category>" %>
```

line at the top of the file.

Finally, in the .aspx I have:

```
<% foreach (var category in ViewData) { %>
    <li>
        <%= Html.ActionLink(category.CategoryName, new { action="List", category=category.CategoryName }) %>
    </li>
<% } %>
```

Two questions:

First, when I browse to /Products/Categories/ I get the error:

**Compiler Error Message:** CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair' does not contain a definition for 'CategoryName' and no extension method 'CategoryName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and the category view data object isn't recognizing any of the properties of the Category class.

What am I missing?

Second, the controller's Category() action method is returning a list of categories (typed as "List categories") as the viewdata for the view, but the view's ActionLink helper method references a "category.CategoryName".  This doesn't make sense to me since I'm passing in an instance of categories (not Category) as the type.  Since the controller's action method is returning a List doesn't this suggest the view needs to be typed as Categories?

**UPDATE:**

I realized a flaw in my question and in my approach to this.  I was more focused on the error and comparing my results to the article I read than on my actual goal - kind of like not seeing the forest through the trees.  When I thought about what I was actually trying to accomplish - passing a model data to the view - I stopped thing about the syntax error and started thinking about (a) the particular object I wanted to create in the controller and (b) which piece(s) of that data I wanted to pass to the view.  Once I saw the forest through the trees, the answer became obvious to me.  @Ufuk and @ryk helped me realize this.

Comment: @Ryk - something seems off in the calculation - I have 22 questions and only 3 doesn't have accepted answers.

Comment: @ryk - I understand about checking vs voting. Check out my comment and profile. Only 3 or 4 not accepted.

Comment: @ryk - I realized a flaw in my question. I'm updating it, please check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should strongly type the View to the List, not the model only.

```
<%@ ... Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MVC_Basics_1.Models.Category>>" %>
```

This should solve both of your problems I guess. First you couldn't browse it with a foreach becase your model was not implementing IEnumerable. Second `List<Category>`  instances are lists, you have to refer to a member if you want to use Category class' properties.

**Update**

There is a problem in your View too. You are sending the list in Model, not in ViewData.Change your View like this:

```
<% foreach (var category in Model) { %>
    <li>
        <%= Html.ActionLink(category.CategoryName, new { action="List", category=category.CategoryName }) %>
    </li>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I am getting the exact same error.  Curious, when I create the view and select to strongly type it, I select "MVC_Basics_1.Models.Category".  Why isn't the listbox giving me the option to pick the List rather than the category?

Comment: It's odd - I'm entering the code as-is from the article, with the exception of changes like RenderView(...) being deprecated in favor of return View(...).  Now that I've specified the <IEnumerable<MVC_Basics_1.Models.Category>> as you suggested, what else do I need to change?

Comment: I realised another error in View. Please see the update. For the other question: I don't know for sure. Intellisense offer classes in Models normally, but you have to specify the place if it's nested.

Comment: I realized a flaw in my question.  I'm updating it, please check it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once, I was passing an integer value as the first parameter for the ActionLink method (when the expected value is a string), so I got this error that was caused for the mistyped parameter data type. I just converted the parameter to string and it worked (ie: myModel.integerProperty.ToString()).

Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ ... Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MVC_Basics_1.Models.Category>" %>
```

needs to be

```
<%@ ... Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<MVC_Basics_1.Models.Category>>" %>
```

You need to be using 'model' in place of ViewData.

```
<% foreach (var category in model) { %>
    <li>
        <%= Html.ActionLink(category.CategoryName, "List", new {category= category.CategoryName }) %>
    </li>
<% } %>
```

ViewData is a hash table, using Key-Value pairs, so iterating through ViewData will give you each object in the hash table, not your Model that you're declaring and passing to the View.

Comment: An interface such as IEnumerable is a better choice.

Comment: @Benjamin-I changed ViewData to "Model" & changed Inherits. Where is "Model" defined? Also is the article referring to "ViewData" vs "Model" because something changed between when the article was written and MVC 1 RTM? Finally, oddly I've now lost visibility to Html.ActionLink: "Compiler Error: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.List<MVC_Basics_1.Models.Category>>' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments".

Comment: @Howiecamp: I've corrected the ActionLink parameters.  It should work now

Comment: I'd love to accept both your answers but apparently not possible.  I'm going to accept the other answer because I think both are equally good but he answered first.  I needed some criteria!